# Boost ASIO multithread application crashes when job are posted between the threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

I am trying to scale a boost single threaded application to a multi threaded application. The code is based on this [article](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.asio-scalability) . The approach I am taking is to have dedicated IO_Context for each thread. In my application I need to post ASIO JOB from other thread to the other thread's IO_Context. As per boost [article](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.asio-scalability) this should work but my application is crashing with segmentation fault after few iterations.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using boost::system::error_code;

static std::atomic_int tid_gen = 0;
thread_local int const tid     = [] { return ++tid_gen; }();
static constexpr auto  now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
static auto const      start   = now();
static std::mutex console_mx;

void trace(auto const&... msg) {
    std::lock_guard lk(console_mx);
    std::cerr << "at " << std::setw(8) << (now() - start)/1ms << "ms - tid:" << tid << " ";
    (std::cerr << ... << msg) << std::endl;
}

void worker(asio::io_context& ioContext) {
    trace("Worker thread enter");
    ioContext.run(); // Run the io_context to handle asynchronous operations
    trace("Worker thread exit");
}

int main() {
    try {
        asio::io_context ioContext1;
        asio::io_context ioContext2;
        std::function<void(const boost::system::error_code& error)> handler1;
        std::function<void(const boost::system::error_code& error)> handler2;

        asio::steady_timer task1(ioContext1, 100ms);
        asio::steady_timer task2(ioContext2, 200ms);

        handler1 = [&task1, &handler1, &ioContext2](error_code ec) {
            //trace("Start Task1: ", ec.message());
            if (!ec)
                usleep(5000);
            asio::post(ioContext2, []{
                trace("Task1 posted job on Task2");
            });
            task1.async_wait(handler1);
        };
        task1.async_wait(handler1);

        handler2 = [&task2, &handler2, &ioContext1](error_code ec) {
            //trace("Start Task2: ", ec.message());
            if (!ec)
                usleep(10000);
            asio::post(ioContext1, []{
                trace("Task2 posted job on Task1");
            });  
            task2.async_wait(handler2);
        };
        task2.async_wait(handler2);


        // Create a work object to prevent ioContext.run() from returning immediately
        auto work1 = make_work_guard(ioContext1);
        auto work2 = make_work_guard(ioContext2);

        // Create multiple worker threads
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
        threads.emplace_back(worker, std::ref(ioContext1));
        threads.emplace_back(worker, std::ref(ioContext2));


        trace("App started :", std::thread::hardware_concurrency());

        work1.reset();
        work2.reset();

        // Join the worker threads
        for (auto& thread : threads) {
            thread.join();
        }

        trace("All worker threads joined.");
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        trace("Exception: ", std::quoted(e.what()));
    }
}
```

Here is the back trace

```
Thread 3 "application" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x763de380 (LWP 29973)]
boost::asio::detail::scheduler::do_run_one (this=this@entry=0x42d188, lock=..., this_thread=..., ec=...) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/scheduler.ipp:458
```

Does anyone know if this approach should work or expected to fail?
I have tried adding separate locks before posting the jobs but that also did not help.

Any other suggestions to make posting jobs between IO_Contexts work would also be very useful.
I am using boost version 1.79 on embedded linux 5.15 platform which is running on Dual Core Cortex A7 hardware.

Comment: What are `io1post_mx` and `io2post_mx`? Couldn't find definition in code.
 And you've got potentian deadlock: locking 2 mutexes in different order. Of cause, it's not the answer to original question.

Comment: thanks @MishaT for pointing that out. I have done the update to the question (I had not removed all the reference). So what I wanted to do with the locks is that before posting the job take a lock which is unique to the io_context but this did not help.

Comment: What is the operation system and IDE?

Comment: I am using boost version 1.79 on embedded linux 5.15 platform which is running on Dual Core Cortex A7 hardware. IDE is yocto GCC.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an issue with the code posted.

I note a few issues: the timers are... useless because all the async_waits immediately complete (except for the first one).

The work guards add no value (because there's always work).

I simplified it to **[this](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/555c040b6be308e1)**.

> *You are also missing exception handling in the `worker` function ([Should the exception thrown by boost::asio::io_service::run() be caught?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500818/should-the-exception-thrown-by-boostasioio-servicerun-be-caught)). I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.*

### Proof of correctness

The only code referencing timer1 is in loop1.
The only code referencing timer2 is in loop2.

loop1/loop2 are implicit strands (they only execute consecutively chaining from their own completion handlers).

`ioc1` and `ioc2` are shared, but [documented thread-safe](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context.html#boost_asio.reference.io_context.thread_safety) (assuming sufficient lifetime, i.e. except construction/destruction), with some exceptions that aren't relevant here:

> Shared objects: Safe, with the specific exceptions of the `restart()` and `notify_fork()` functions. Calling restart() while there are unfinished run(), `run_one()`, `run_for()`, `run_until()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()` calls results in undefined behaviour. The `notify_fork()` function should not be called while any `io_context` function, or any function on an I/O object that is associated with the `io_context`, is being called in another thread.

### Simplify - Encapsulate

If you intended the async timers to reschedule at regular intervals, I've previously done some examples to encapsulate that logic so you don't need to repeat so much code.

Also, it should decouple the timers from the execution context, as it is perfectly valid to run many timers on a single context/thread if so desired. Of course, if the task(s) are CPU-heavy you should not be invoking them from the (same) service thread.

See [Asio async_wait gives Operation canceled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76819327/asio-async-wait-gives-operation-canceled/76820534#76820534) for the full explanation.

### Simplify - Thread pool and strands

To remedy the lack of exception handling, and also the juggling of many (redundant) contexts, I suggest using a shared context. Now, you can still make sure that all handlers are *serialized* on a specific "task" by using strands.

> This is the method that you appeared to have been looking for when you said [*"So what I wanted to do with the locks is that before posting the job take a lock which is unique to the io_context but this did not help"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77057112/boost-asio-multithread-application-crashes-when-job-are-posted-between-the-threa#comment135843947_77057112).
>
> The reason it doesn't help is that
>
> - you want to serialize handler *invocation*, not the time of queuing
> - you cannot hold a lock over async invocations, because it breaks the executor abstraction: executors can cause the handler to be invoked on a different thread, where the lock will not be held. Theoretically you could hold a `unique_lock` inside your move-only handler object, but I would consider this a strong code-smell 99% of the time (and a recipe for deadlocks)

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0d6a47f1dd2f616)**

```
static constexpr auto unit = 1000ms;
asio::thread_pool ioc(2); // or leave the argument to get a system-dependent default size
std::function<void(error_code error)> loop1, loop2;

auto make_loop = [](auto& loop, int id, auto ex, auto otherEx) {
    auto interval = id * unit;
    loop = [=, &loop, t = std::make_shared<asio::steady_timer>(ex, interval)](error_code ec) {
        trace("Start Task", id, ": ", ec.message());
        if (!ec)
            sleep_for(interval / 2);
        asio::post(otherEx, [id] { trace("job cross-posted from Task", id); });
        t->expires_from_now(interval);
        t->async_wait(loop);
    };

    asio::post(ex, bind(loop, error_code{})); // prime the pump
};

auto task1 = make_strand(ioc);
auto task2 = make_strand(ioc);
make_loop(loop1, 1, task1, task2);
make_loop(loop2, 2, task2, task1);

trace("App started :", std::thread::hardware_concurrency());
ioc.join();
```

Printing

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -DCOLIRU && ./a.out
at        0ms - tid:0 main
at        0ms - tid:1 Start Task1: Success
at        0ms - tid:0 App started :4
at        0ms - tid:2 Start Task2: Success
at     1000ms - tid:1 job cross-posted from Task2
at     1000ms - tid:2 job cross-posted from Task1
at     1500ms - tid:1 Start Task1: Success
at     2001ms - tid:1 job cross-posted from Task1
at     3000ms - tid:2 Start Task2: Success
at     3001ms - tid:1 Start Task1: Success
at     4001ms - tid:2 job cross-posted from Task2
at     4001ms - tid:1 job cross-posted from Task1
at     4501ms - tid:2 Start Task1: Success
at     5001ms - tid:2 job cross-posted from Task1
at     6001ms - tid:1 Start Task2: Success
at     6001ms - tid:2 Start Task1: Success
at     7001ms - tid:1 job cross-posted from Task2
at     7001ms - tid:2 job cross-posted from Task1
at     7502ms - tid:1 Start Task1: Success
at     8002ms - tid:1 job cross-posted from Task1
at     9001ms - tid:2 Start Task2: Success
at     9002ms - tid:1 Start Task1: Success
at    10001ms - tid:0 All worker threads joined.
```

Note how this is effectively 28 lines of code less than your initial repro - 33% liposuction.

### Summary/Conclusion

To be completely fair, you probably really need task queues and dedicated threads instead of shoe-horning io_context to be your queuing mechanism. Using the IntervalTimer above you could integrate that nicely to have Asio manage the timers.

Comment: Thanks @sehe for the response. I tried your [code](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/555c040b6be308e1) with modification to reduce the unit time to 10ms and to run the code for 100 seconds. The code crashes with SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault after few seconds. Even with original code in the post it was working but crashing after many seconds. I have tried the code with even latest version1.83 and see the same behavior. Do you any insights if it could be specific to platform / compiler specific optimizations/behaviors ?

Comment: Hmm. That's weird. I've run it with small units and long time as well. I even disabled output tracing to avoid hiding races by synchronizing on `console_mx`. I don't currently have a good idea what else could cause this. Except the general reasons for code to fail: [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) of the general kind, like [ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition), ABI. It might be platform specific, but I highly doubt it. If you cannot fix it, and it is actually reproducible with this sample, you might open an issue with the Asio repository.